# Recognize a referenced dll missing

Tags: c#, windows, dll, desktop-application

I'm work with Visual Studio 2022.
I prepared some DLL libraries that i'm going to use in my app with reference.
For any reason, if the DLL is missing in the application's executable file folder, the app will not start without any message to the user.

The only way i've found to warn the user is to verify that the DLL exists with File.Exists().
Is there any other way?
Thank you.

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework / Standard / Core are you using?

Comment: Check out the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event.

Comment: You should also define what kind of *desktop application* you have there. It may affect the *when* and *where* you can handle this. For example, you could handle `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException`, which would tell you which exception has been thrown and also what assembly is missing. `[ResolveEventArgs].Name` can also tell you that, it depends on how you want to handle this

Comment: BTW, what's the reason why an assembly would go missing, in your scenario? Maybe you could pack the application (whatever that is) in a single file

Comment: If your program won't even start I don't see how your program could warn the user. I suppose you could write a separate program, e.g. `Launcher.exe` or something, that checks dependencies and launches the main program.

Comment: @Jimi, i used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException and now there is error notification. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IL Merge, in this utility, you can merge all the referenced DLLs into your DLLs, so no matter if we have the DLLs exist or not in the folder.

For more information, please read below.

[MS Build.IL Merge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.ILMerge.Task/#:%7E:text=MSBuild%20ILMerge%20task%20allows%20you,MSBuild.)

Answer (score -1):

If you have those references in your `.csproj` file you shouldn't have any problem. Those DLLs will be copied to the `obj` folder for you.

Comment: The `obj` or `bin`?  Either way, being put there by the build process doesn't guarantee that the DLL will remain there until the end of time.  Question asks what to do if the DLL is missing "for any reason".